# Scrollbar issues in div with fixed header

Tags: css, css-position, fixed

Now I'm creating a page which contains a div with fixed height and scrollbar. 
Unfortunately this div also has fixed header. The problem is: fixed header overlaps scrollbar, so that it is impossible to use scrollbar clicking by right part of fixed header.
Possible workarounds for such problem are:

1) custom scrollbar of certain width

2) simple resize handler that updates fixed header width making it equal to .content block width.

But this workarounds need js.

Can I solve the problem in pure css?

To make things more clear, I make an example of such problem in sandbox.

Thanks!

CODEPEN:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GGRVRP

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Fixed header, long enough to demonstrate that scrollbar can't be triggered by clicking on header</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, eum sapiente non, natus et, ullam unde odio quos quo blanditiis aspernatur minus quas? Architecto enim iure itaque reiciendis cupiditate, et consequatur natus praesentium aspernatur voluptas illum odit eius distinctio doloribus animi iusto, repudiandae, maiores sint laudantium id unde veritatis! Suscipit odio obcaecati possimus nisi culpa autem deleniti dolores inventore commodi ex sed consectetur modi cupiditate eveniet, omnis repellendus placeat ab iste fuga harum esse quod enim excepturi minus? Similique, alias est doloremque deserunt tempora dolore delectus, eligendi veritatis ipsum, dolorum tenetur id quod cum rerum vero amet tempore laborum nam.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: coral;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: violet;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use position: sticky may it helps you

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 240px;
  height: 500px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: coral;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 224px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: violet;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Fixed header, long enough to demonstrate that scrollbar can't be triggered by clicking on header</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, eum sapiente non, natus et, ullam unde odio quos quo blanditiis aspernatur minus quas? Architecto enim iure itaque reiciendis cupiditate, et consequatur natus praesentium aspernatur voluptas illum odit eius distinctio doloribus animi iusto, repudiandae, maiores sint laudantium id unde veritatis! Suscipit odio obcaecati possimus nisi culpa autem deleniti dolores inventore commodi ex sed consectetur modi cupiditate eveniet, omnis repellendus placeat ab iste fuga harum esse quod enim excepturi minus? Similique, alias est doloremque deserunt tempora dolore delectus, eligendi veritatis ipsum, dolorum tenetur id quod cum rerum vero amet tempore laborum nam.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your need to compensate for the header by adding margin top not padding. And you will have no problem.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: coral;
}
```

https://codepen.io/draganradu/pen/BVyBpW